# How does FUDGE compare to other rulebooks?

Tags: fudge

[FUDGE](http://www.fudgerpg.com/) seems appealing for its laxity. What does it do particularly well/poorly compared to popular rulebooks like D&D, World of Darkness, etc.?

Specifically, I'm thinking of starting either a Fallout, Deus Ex, or Matrix campaign. Would FUDGE or some other rulebook be especially suited for these universes?

Comment: This is still rather open ended, and the first paragraph in particular is an invitation to subjectivity. Also, are you asking about FUDGE's suitability to these campaign types, or about which system would be best for these campaign types?

Comment: The nature of the setting and what sorts of things you want to focus on (including how much action is social, mental, and physical/combat) and ease of play are vital.

Comment: I understand this question to be a paraphrase of **Would Fudge be appropriate to run a  Fallout, Deus Ex, or Matrix campaign?**  Mcandre, could you please clarify/edit your question so that it is clear what you mean?  Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about rule systems rather then rule books.

Comment: Hey - closing till we get an edit.  This is at least two completely separate questions and both are very poorly defined, please see the faq on asking clear and constructive questions you can get an answer to, this is more just "invitation to discussion."

Comment: I'd suggest question 1 of "What are the major advantages/disadvantaged of FUDGE versus popular trad rulesets like D&D and WoD" and question 2 of "Would FUDGE be a good fit to run my gritty action futuristic campaing (like Deus Ex, Fallout, Matrix)?"  And clarify a LOT what it is you want out of that latter - explicit rules support?  Prep time reduction? What do you want out of a game, so people can tell you if it'll help?  "A future game" is so vague that answers are just yammering.

Comment: Though the question itself is literally unclear, the question being asked is clear enough to me: "I don't know what FUDGE is good for. What is it good for? For context I'm pondering these campaigns." I tried to address that question in my answer.

Comment: Sardathrion has it. I'm asking what the pros/cons of Fudge would be for a campaign over popular rulesets like D&D and WoD.

Comment: That's not a good question unless you share a little more about what you want out of a game...

Answer (score 5):

FUDGE is a toolkit, not a complete game system like D&D and WoD. What it does well is be clay in the GM's hands that is easily molded into a form that suits the kind of game you want to run. It doesn't bring with it a lot of setting or themes that are embedded in the mechanics like more focused systems. On the downside, it doesn't bring with it a lot of built-in themes or implied setting elements. FUDGE provides a core resolution system and some best-practices advice for how to use it, and how to structure character abilities and such. It requires significant setup before play in order to support a given game concept, but its flexibility lends itself to adaptation to any given game concept.

Answer (score 3):

The [Fudge RPG site](http://www.fudgerpg.com/goodies/fudge-files/core/) has the rules available for free.  You maybe interested in [Fate](http://www.faterpg.com/resources/) as well which you can get for free. Either would be eminently suitable for modelling a rpg from either a computer game or movie.  Both those systems are tool-kits to enhance storytelling more than a model of reality using probabilities.  So, if you are looking at a tactical board game with RPG elements set in New Vegas, then I would recommend D&D (or just play Fallout!).  If you are looking for a story focused with character developmental (in the literary sense) RPG, then either Fate or Fudge would work well.

Note that neither systems come set up to play either a Fallout, Deus Ex, or Matrix campaigns.  You will need to do some work to make them mesh.  However, I do not believe it will be much work.

Answer (score 1):

Although FATE and FUDGE are good storytelling mechanisms work is required to adapt them to the world system you want to use.

My specific concern would be if you wanted to run a campaign based in the Matrix universe then some kind of mechanics for duality of the worlds needs to be taken into account; a system like Cyberpunk (or shadowrun) might be more appropriate; which is definitely more rules heavy but is a fairly streamlined system.

Comment: Why would Fate/Fudge not be suitable for a dual (or multi) verse setting?

Comment: Conceptually Fate/Fudge is an open book to any system you care to throw at it, but you have to design said concepts etc for the duality. My thoughts were that the stated systems already handle the Net/Matrix/Cyberspace mechanics for you and therefore save you some hassle.

Comment: I fail to see how the matrix and the net are even close to being similar...

Comment: Well, as a starter; in cyberpunk all interactions in the net are driven from the int stat, in the Matrix your mind is what determines how powerful/fast/etc you are.

Comment: Hmm. On first blush, I think that duality would not be much of a problem for any ruleset: simply assign each character dual stats, one for the real world and one for the simulated world. In the Matrix, for example, you could have +2 to Flying while in the Matrix which would not even be an option in the real world.

Comment: Fair point @mcandre, the double development requirements could also leave you with the classic nerd in the real world who is a god unto others in the Matrix. :)